# How to validate so that no repetition of name allowed in Existing list c#

Tags: c#, list, validation, methods, repeat

1.this is the code

```
private List<Model1> _projectVariables { get; set; } = new List<Model1>();
 public void AddProject(Model1 project)  // i want to perform validation         
{           
  _projectVariables.Add(project); //this method add user input to the list
}
```

what should i write in the Above code so that no repetition of data is allowed in the list.
what should i do???

Comment: You can use a `HashSet` instead of `List`

Comment: Have a look at [List<T>.Contains(T)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.contains?view=net-6.0)

Comment: Can you show `Model1` class? Which property is considered to define that project is unique or not? `HashSet` is the best option here I believe. If you don;t want to change Type of `_projectVariables` then you can look for `List.Contains()` or `.Any()` method from Linq.

Comment: public Model1(string id, string name, string Startdate, string Enddate)
        {
            PId = id;
            PName = name;
            PStartDate = Startdate;
            PEndDate = Enddate;
        }
        public string PId { get; set; }
        public string PName { get; set; }
        public string PStartDate { get; set; }
        public string PEndDate { get; set; } @Prasad Telkikar

Comment: @daya08, can you try solution suggested by Izzy, ggeorgy

Comment: i know but i have to do with List only....that is the Requirment @Prasad Telkikar

Answer (score 0):

Use `Contains` to check if that object already exists in the List before Adding it

```
private List<Model1> _projectVariables { get; set; } = new List<Model1>();
public void AddProject(Model1 project)  // i want to perform validation         
{       
   if (!_projectVariables.Contains(project)){
      _projectVariables.Add(project);
  }
}
```

Another option is using Hashsets which allow you to add unique values into a collection. So if you have a rule that no two identical objects are added to a collection (like in your case) then a Set is a good choice.

```
private HashSet<Model1> _projectVariables { get; set; } = new HashSet<Model1>();
public void AddProject(Model1 project)  // i want to perform validation         
{       
      _projectVariables.Add(project);
}
```

If you want to check if two different objects which are referencing different objects in the memory already exist in the list, you can check it via `Any` like so:

```
Any(x => x.someProp1 == project.someProp1 && x.someProp2 == project.someProp2 )
```

Comment: its not working still its taking repeated data which i am providing....can you give me another solution using list @Ran Turner

Comment: If you want to check based on a certain property, you can check it via `Any(x => x.someProp1 == project.someProp1 && x.someProp2 == project.someProp2 )`

Comment: Actually i am new in c# ..where should i put this code Line??

Comment: In your validation to check for same objects

Comment: thank you everyone ...its working now

Comment: Great, would appreciate if you can accept the answer and vote up